# Why do i get Mysqli not found when I run my php spark serve?

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp

So I imported mysql data to phpadmin, under codeigniter and xampp, but when I run the code, I got an error of `Class "mysqli" not found`

[image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KdJn.png)

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "sex_disaggrated";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                }
```

I already change the **.env **file. into this one

```
database.default.hostname = localhost
database.default.database = sex_disaggrated
database.default.username = root
database.default.password = 
database.default.DBDriver = MySQLi
```

EDIT:

[Php Mysqli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3lXP.png)

Comment: Do you have mysqli enabled in PHP settings?

Comment: Yes, I have already enabled it.